# Adding Swagger to ASP.Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to add Swagger to my ASP.Net Core Web API project, like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
       services.AddControllers();
       services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
       {
          c.SwaggerDoc("v0.1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v0.1" });
       });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            ...
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v0.1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            ...
}
```

but I am getting this error:

> The type or namespace name 'OpenApiInfo' could not be found

I have installed Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v4.0.1, and my project is .Net Core 3.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because the type `OpenApiInfo` comes together with the latest version of `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`; open the nuget packages manager, tick the 'include prerelease' checkbox and update the package to version 5.0.0-rc3.

And then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Latest version of [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) package from NuGet Package Manager then it will work.